AzureDevops Server 2008- Workitem Cascading filed are not working
We are using AzureDevops Server 2008, and we couldnt find any feature available to create Workitems with cascading fields. We were trying to create some workflow/process for our support requests and planned to have some field hierarchy as below. But no plugins or features are available in the ADO.


There was no such thing as "Azure DevOps Server 2008". Do you mean TFS 2008? Are you really using TFS 2008? In 2024? Please invest some effort in updating to a version released in the past decade.

On Azure DevOps Services (cloud) and Azure DevOps Server/TFS (on-prem), there is no built-in Cascading control.
In the Marketplace, most of the Cascading related extensions are only available for Azure DevOps Services (cloud).
However, I noticed that the following two extensions also can be available for Azure DevOps Server/TFS (on-prem):

Dependent Lists


Multi-Pickers Fields Control



Since TFS 2008 is a so old version and had been end of support, not sure whether the two extensions can be compatible and work with TFS 2008. You can try to install and use them on your TFS 2008. If they cannot work, I'm afraid that you might need to upgrade the TFS 2008 to a newer version of Azure DevOps Server/TFS that can work with the extensions.


TFS 2008 barely even had support for CI (MSBuild-only, pre-dating XAML builds), let alone support for extensions. Don't even confuse the issue by recommending extensions. Extension support was first added in TFS 2012 if I recall correctly, and TFS 2015 was the first to support anything resembling a modern extension, although I doubt anything created recently would be backwards compatible that far. The correct answer here is "upgrade". Let me put it in perspective: TFS 2008 didn't even have a web interface.

@DanielMann, Thanks for your clarification and sharing more information.

I couldnt achieve this .. as the steps as given are not clear

@Bright Ran-MSFT, Now we upgraded ADo server 2022. and installed this extension. But stiill there is no instruction on how to get the above scenario done. The above listed extension documents are not clear
